# Who are the "princes" that Hela refers to?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, thor-marvel, thor-ragnarok

In the movie *Thor: Ragnarok (2017)*, Hela, the goddess of death, says to Hogun, who has been standing in-front of her:

> "It's come to my attention that you don't know who I am. I am Hela,
>   Odin's firstborn... the commander of the Legions  of Asgard...the
>   rightful heir to the throne, and the Goddess  of Death. My father is
>   dead. **As are the princes**."

Answer (score 30, accepted):

### She refers to Thor and Loki

Both Thor and Loki, as true-born/recognized sons of Odin, are the princes of Asgard.

She assumes that they have either died during the Bifrost transport, or she is simply bluffing in order to gain support and recognition in Asgard.